# Django - Get string from ModelForm field label

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've got the following: I want to add a string to my ModelForm field labels. I want to do it in the form class.

I do this:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = MyEntity

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for key in self.fields:                                
           self.fields[key].label = "-- " + self.fields[key].label
```

I always get the following in my template:

> -- django.utils.functional.**proxy** object at 0x04605E10>

The label contains in `proxy___args` under 0 the correct label. How can I get this label? Can't be that hard, can it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is that the label is a **string array**. You need to join the array bits to a string like this:

```
self.fields[key].label = "-- %s" % string.join(self.fields[key].label, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this working?:

```
from django.utils.translation import string_concat

for key in self.fields:
    self.fields[key].label = string_concat("-- ", self.fields[key].label)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because your label is a `ugettext_lazy` object and can't be mixed in with a regular string. from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#working-with-lazy-translation-objects):

> The result of a ugettext_lazy() call can be used wherever you would use a unicode string 
>   (an object with type unicode) in Python. If you try to use it where a bytestring (a str 
>   object) is expected, things will not work as expected, since a ugettext_lazy() object 
>   doesn’t know how to convert itself to a bytestring. You can’t use a unicode string 
>   inside a bytestring, either, so this is consistent with normal Python behavior.... If 
>   you ever see output that looks like "hello <django.utils.functional...>", you have tried 
>   to insert the result of ugettext_lazy() into a bytestring.

Try using `u"-- "` instead. mariodev's `string_concat` suggestion should work too.